# Best practice to support 256 color cterm colors in highlight

Tags: vim

I took my first dip into the iTerm2/vim/vimux landscape from the land of gui MacVim. The immediate first problem I am having is that several plugins I use support very poor 8color highlights when in cterm land. So, I want to improve them as much as possible...

I've looked at some of the [wikia recommendations](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/256_colors_in_vim), and found how the colorschemes that support 256 colors to [see how they did it](https://github.com/ciaranm/inkpot/blob/master/colors/inkpot.vim). Looks somewhat straight forward, but...

Anybody else done this before? I hate to attack this problem in three plugins if there is already a supporting library out there to make the job easier.

Comment: Why don't you list the 3 plugins and the problems you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't touch your plugins. You only need to change the terminal type in iTerm2's settings to `xterm-256colors`.

I don't have a Mac at hand right now but I know it's very easy to find.

If your colorscheme is GUI-only, you can use CSApprox or some similar plugin to transform it in a 256-colors colorscheme.

Answer (score 0):

Plugins should define their highlightings via `:hi def MyGroup ...`. With that, you can override the defaults in your `~/.vimrc` via

```
:hi MyGroup ctermfg=... ctermbg=...
```

Should the plugin miss the `def` part, you can still override the highlightings *after* the plugin was sourced (e.g. in a `~/.vim/after/plugin/` script).

But I agree with romainl that first and foremost, make sure to get the 256 colors in your terminal, and use CSApprox to adapt your colorscheme to the high-color terminal, should your favorite colorscheme not support it out of the box.